# C++ conversion to C# reading text to generate statements

Tags: c#, c++

I have a c++ program that reads a text file with form feed as page/document delimiter.

I can scan the text file and catch the form feed as needed. What has me flummoxed at the moment is an oddness in an if() statement.

I have a c++ variable defined as such:

```
DWORD dwTotalReadStmts;
```

and in another class, I have the following method:

```
BOOL CAG_StatementParser::GetFirstStatement(CAG_Statement& Statement)
```

The above BOOL method has a return from a ReadStatement(Statement) method that reads the statement and does various bits of work on the lines read from the text file.

In the main, I have an if statement that uses the DWORD to evaluate a Boolean returned from a method.  As I understand, the DWORD is an unsigned long integer value.

```
CAG_Statement Statement;
int nStmts = -1;
if (dwTotalReadStmts = Parser.GetFirstStatement(Statement))
```

I am trying to wrap my brain around how the if statement works.  When I try something similar in C#, I get an error on type conflict (cannot implicitly convert 'bool' to 'int').

Here is the c++ code I need to convert to c#

```
CAG_StatementParser Parser;
if (Parser.Open(m_DataFileName.GetFilePathName()))
{
    CAG_Statement Statement;
    int nStmts = -1;
    if (dwTotalReadStmts = Parser.GetFirstStatement(Statement))
    {
nStmts = 1;
cout << setw(6) << nStmts << "\r";

/* Write first statement */
if (!WriteStatement(Statement))
{
    CleanUp(); return 1;
}

/* Write subsequent statement */
while ((dwTotalReadStmts = Parser.GetNextStatement(Statement)) == 1)
{
    if (Statement.m_nTotalPages == 0)
break;

    if (!WriteStatement(Statement))
    {
break;
    }

    cout << setw(6) << nStmts++ << "\r";

}

/* DONE! ->  clean up */
CleanUp();

    }

    if (nStmts == -1) {
cout << "No statement processed!" << endl;
    }
    else {

/* Display statistics */
ShowStats();

if (nStmts != dwTotalReadStmts) {
    CString strTmp;
    m_strLog += "There may exist an error when processing the input file.\r\n";
    if (dwTotalReadStmts > 1) {
strTmp.Format("Total statements parsed does not agree with audit counts: %d vs %d!!!\r\n", nStmts, dwTotalReadStmts);
    }
    else {
strTmp.Format("Only parsed %d statements from the input file!!!\r\n", nStmts);
    }
    m_strLog += strTmp;
}

DumpLog(m_strLog);
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "Could not open statement file!" << endl;
}
```

Here is the skeleton of C# code I have so far

```
StatementParser parser = new StatementParser();
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
if (fileStream.CanRead)
{
    Statement statement = new Statement();
    int nStmts = -1;
    if (nTotalReadStmts = StatementParser.GetFirstStatment(fileStream, out statement))
    {
        nStmts = 1;
        Console.WriteLine(nStmts);

        //write first statement
        if (!WriteStatement(statement))
        {
CleanUp();
return false;
        }

        //srite sebsequent statements
        while ((nTotalReadStmts = StatementParser.GetNextStatment(fileStream, out statement)) == 1)
        {
if (statement.M_nPages ==0)
{
    break;
}
if(!WriteStatement(statement))
{
    break;
}

Console.WriteLine(nStmts);
        }
        CleanUp();
    }

    if(nStmts == -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No statment processed.");
    }
    else
    {
        /* Display statistics */
        //ShowStats();

        if(nStmts != nTotalReadStmts)
        {
String strTmp = ""; ;
//write log file entry
if(nTotalReadStmts > 1)
{
    strTmp += string.Format("Totals do not agree: {0} vs {1}", nStmts, nTotalReadStmts);
}
else
{
    strTmp += string.Format("Parsed {0} statements from the input file", nStmts);
}

//add strTmp to log file
        }
        //write the logfile 
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cannot read file.");
}
```

Comment: C# `if` statements require a genuine boolean argument, there's no assumption that nonzero == true like in C / C++. So `if (nTotalReadStmts = StatementParser.GetFirstStatment(fileStream, out statement))` doesn't work as the assignment returns the assigned value as a side-effect, which isn't boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, this...

```
if (dwTotalReadStmts = Parser.GetFirstStatement(Statement)) 
{
    //  ...
```

Is equal to this:

```
dwTotalReadStmts = Parser.GetFirstStatement(Statement);

if (dwTotalReadStmts != 0)
{
    //  ...
```

That's because

1. In C and C++, an integer value of zero is a boolean false, and a nonzero integer value is a boolean true. They're interchangeable in those languages, but in C# they aren't.
2. In either language, an assignment expression returns the value assigned:

   ```
   int x = 1;
   int y = 2;
   //  Now z is equal to 1
   int z = (y = x);
   ```

   This is done to filter out the weaklings in CS101.

So it's calling GetFirstStatement(), assigning the (unsigned long) return value to dwTotalReadStmts, and then interpreting that same unsigned long value as a boolean.

The second version is valid C# just the way it is, assuming that `Parser.GetFirstStatement(Statement)` still returns some kind of integer -- although in C# we wouldn't use the `dw` prefix to indicate a `DWORD`.

Answer (score 1):

The if-statement

```
if (dwTotalReadStmts = Parser.GetFirstStatement(Statement))
{
    // do something
}
```

is exactly the same as

```
dwTotalReadStmts = Parser.GetFirstStatement(Statement);
if (dwTotalReadStmts != 0)
{
    // do something
}
```